# How to integrate AdColony with AdMob mediation in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-ad-mediation, firebase-admob

I'm using firebase_admob to implement AdMob mediation in my flutter app
I've implemented the AdColony with AdMob mediation for android, I've followed these instructions:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/adcolony

And now I'm willing to implement it with IOS, I'm following these instructions:
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/mediation/adcolony

I don't have any experience with IOS app development, so where to find the PodFile so I can add this
`pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationAdColony'`
and also after putting it, where should I run this command `pod install --repo-update`

Comment: you can find the podfile in the Project Structure, if its not there yet create one, and you can run pod install --repo-update in the Console

Comment: @Nuqo should I have mac os?